# Is the placement of "again" in the following sentence incorrect?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Were the money to be again offered this year, I would accept it.

Comment: That depends on where you live and the company you keep! (Just joking.) Some grammarians would say the adverb "again" should come after the word "offered." Others are a little more flexible and allow the rule to be broken with impunity. Don

Comment: If a rule may be broken with impunity, is it a rule? Placing 'again' before the verb it modifies is in this example totally grammatical, but takes us into a highly formal register. But starting with 'Were the money' instead of 'If X/they offered' has taken us there already.

Comment: You can even put 'again' after 'year' if you like.